# Why the aggressive migration of comments to chat?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

Post I'm referring to: [What are the differences between credential stuffing and password spraying?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209266/what-are-the-differences-between-credential-stuffing-and-password-spraying)  I don't recall seeing mods move short discussions from answer comments to chat before.  Usually this moderation action is reserved for people having a very long back and forth discussion, and even that is fairly rare.

In my opinion, moving comments to chat should be reserved for extreme situations since most users won't be likely to follow the link, and thus will miss out on the information they provide.  While I understand some people believe that ["comments are not for anything permanent"](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2426/converting-long-comment-threads-to-chat-hides-potentially-useful-comments/2428#2428), the de facto practice on the site has been to preserve them.

Answer (score 6):

The de facto practice on this site (and for most of SE) has always been to remove comments. They are absolutely considered temporary, and only useful if they help an answer get updates or edits for clarification.

Those comments were not useful at all - Motivated added basically the same comment to every post, which just adds noise, especially as the comment was their opinion, not what the others or in fact what industry typically uses - so it was basically just highlighting their mistaken understanding of what the terms mean.

The answers have not lost anything from those comments being moved, and in fact are much easier to read.